# Suitable table (latex-code) for recording experimental results by hand

Tags: tables

I am preparing a document for students to record their experimental results. What is a suitable table for the recording of results in particular? Suitable tables should have large cells for handwriting. In my case only two columns (many rows) are required, one column is attempt # and the other one is speed or reaction time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just need a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%% #1=width
%% #2=height
\def\cellDimensions#1#2{\rule{#1}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{#2}}
\def\resultRow{\cellDimensions{1cm}{1cm} & \cellDimensions{3cm}{1cm} \\\hline}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
  Attempt \#   & Speed/reaction time \\\hline
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
  \resultRow
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By defining `\resultRow` as I have, I can easily adjust the cell widths and heights.  The height of the row will be the height of the tallest cell declared.